# Simple mediaPlayer example doesn't work! Why?

Tags: android, media-player

From the Developer Guide I took this simple example:

```
               MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
               mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

But there is no sound!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check your media volume in your mobile (or) below code for playing sound file :

This is Worked for me:

```
    public void play()
    {
        Thread playThread = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(VastuActivity.this, R.raw.click);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        };

        playThread.start();
    }
```

call the method `play();`

Answer (score 0):

You got everything right. The only reason it may not work is some problem with the sound, may be the file you are using is not supported(in that case you should see some exceptions thrown in all messages tab) or it's just your device